# Populate a dropdown inside an include PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have an index.php which calls the DB connection and populates the page.
If a condition is met an include will be called upon with a dropdown list.
I am unable to populate this dropdown, it gives me no error just a blank screen.

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('db_connection.php');
if($_GET["cat"] === "contact"){
        include ('includes/contact.php');
    }
    else{
        include ('includes/route.php');
    }
?>
```

contact.php:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dropdown_town";
$result = $dbhandle->query($sql);
$town = $result->fetch_assoc();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($town)) {
 echo "<option value='" . $row['zip'] . "'>" . $row['townname'] . " </option>";
 }
?>
```

My DB has a table called dropdown_town with the columns ID, zip and townname
I only posted the PHP code here as the rest of the page runs ok

Comment: Did you get the result from your query. if not checked then just do print_r($town) after fetching record;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following changes in your **contact.php**

You forgot yo write **select** and directly write **option** because of that you got the blank page.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dropdown_town";
$result = $dbhandle->query($sql);
echo "<select name="selectboxname">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<option value='" . $row['zip'] . "'>" . $row['townname'] . " </option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: The select was written earlier as I wanted a blank option in the form:

Code:
'
    <select name="town" id="town" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dropdown_town";
    $result = $dbhandle->query($sql);
    $town = $result->fetch_assoc();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($town)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['zip'] . "'>" . $row['townname'] . " </option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
'

Comment: If I remove the While and only use the echo line where I change $row to $result I get 1 option, the first from the DB.
It seems that the while routine doesn't like to run for some reason

Comment: No need to remove while loop and give me your new  changes so that i can check.

Comment: did you get options? As i have seen you have added LIMIT 1 in your query. this will fetch only one record from the database

Comment: Removed the Limit 1 and the code below works (only 1 option, since I comment out the while, when I uncomment it, blank screen again :(

<code>
<select name="town" id="town" required>  
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dropdown_town ORDER BY zip"; $result = $dbhandle->query($sql); $town = $result->fetch_assoc();
//  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($town)) {
echo "<option value='" . $town['zip'] . "'>" . $town['townname'] . "</option>";
//}
?>
</select>
</code>

Comment: No, it doesnt work, the while loop gives a blank screen :(
btw: how to comment the code nicely?

Comment: what you get in $town, just do print_r($town); then  check and let me know what you will get in  my $town

Comment: The following worked :)
    $sql = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT * FROM dropdown_town ORDER BY zip");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value=\"test1\">" . $row['townname'] . "</option>";
  }
Kind regards

Comment: Found that out :)